# How to select custom waiting time before putting screen to sleep in Mate Power Management?

Tags: suspend, power-management, mate, ubuntu-mate

Simple and probably very dumb question, but I'm very new to Linux and I don't really know where to look for something like this

I'm trying to set a custom wait/idle time before putting the screen to sleep. I wanted to put around 2/3 minutes of waiting time whoever the lowest preset there is, is 5

While clicking the help button I can see there is (or use to be) a way to set it up with sliders which could potentially let me choose something more specific

Is there  way to make it so i can use sliders, or just to get a custom value in anyway?

Anyone who could help?

My mate power manager window

[image: My mate power manager window]

The Power manager window in the help menu

[image: The Power manager window in the help menu]

Comment: What is your Ubuntu MATE version?

Comment: @N0rbert its MATE 1.24.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set these options using commandline

```
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-ac 1800
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager sleep-display-ac 1200

gsettings set org.mate.power-manager sleep-computer-battery 180
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager sleep-display-battery 120
```

where numbers are seconds.

Comment: this is definitely a solution, and while im satisfied with it, I would like to ask, is there a way to do this with a GUI? Im ok with using the command line, but a GUI would definitely be more convenient

Comment: You can find these options in `dconf-editor` and change them from here.

Comment: dconf-editor be the preferred answer for anyone coming here from google search as different systems use different values. For example, Mint uses:  `org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power`